# How does the Journal in Do: Pilgrims of the Flying Temple affect play of the game?

Tags: indie-rpg, do-pilgrims-of-the-flying-temple

I just played [Do: Pilgrims of the Flying Temple](http://danielsolisblog.blogspot.com/2007/08/do-pilgrims-of-flying-temple.html) for the first time on Thursday. It went very well. I played again on Saturday, it did not go as well...  It almost seemed like the journal was a distraction at times. Was this just a symptom of the group, or has someone else had this experience as well?

Comment: was it different groups? what was your group composition in the two different sessions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got to play Do: PotFT twice with Daniel Solis at GenCon. Under his expert direction, we always assured that someone besides the current player was writing in the journal. Usually, the person who's turn just ended, so there would be plenty of time for them to finish before it became their turn again.

The journal never became a distraction.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case, but wasn't sure.